# Foreign-key to this parent is stored in child's table as zero

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When persisting parent object (with one-to-many relationship with child), the foreign-key to this parent is stored in child's table as zero.
My classes:

**Extracting the data from a xls file**

```
public Map<String, Contrato> extraiDados() throws IOException {
    String path = "C:\\Users\\tathiana.i.oliveira\\Desktop\\contratos.xls";
    Map<String, Contrato> mapa = new HashMap<String, Contrato>();
    List<Historico> historicosList;
    Util u = new Util();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFCell cell;
    HSSFRow row;
    int rowsCount = worksheet.getLastRowNum();
    Contrato contrato;
    Historico historico;
    String contratoKey;
    for (int i = 1; i <= rowsCount; i++) {
        try {
            row = worksheet.getRow(i);
            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("L"));
            contratoKey = u.devolveCampoLido(cell);

            if (mapa.containsKey(contratoKey)) {
                contrato = mapa.get(contratoKey);
                historicosList = contrato.getHistoricos();
            } else {
                contrato = new Contrato();
                historicosList = new ArrayList<Historico>();
            }

            contrato.setContrato(contratoKey);
            historico = new Historico();

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("A"));
            contrato.setClassificacao(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("B"));
            contrato.setResponsavel(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("C"));
            contrato.setUf(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("D"));
            contrato.setSigla(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("E"));
            contrato.setStatusContrato(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("F"));
            contrato.setFornecedor(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("G"));
            contrato.setSite(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("H"));
            contrato.setTelefone(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("I"));
            contrato.setCnpj(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("J"));
            contrato.setCodigoFornecedor(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("K"));
            contrato.setHidrometro(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("M"));
            contrato.setNome(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("N"));
            contrato.setEndereco(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("O"));
            contrato.setDespesa(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("P"));
            contrato.setDescricao(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("Q"));
            contrato.setMp(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("T"));
            contrato.setStatus(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("U"));
            contrato.setEstadoLancamento(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("R"));
            historico.setDataCobranca(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("S"));
            historico.setDataVencimento(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("V"));
            historico.setDataEmissao(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("Y"));
            historico.setDataLancamento(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("Z"));
            historico.setDataCompensacao(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("AA"));
            historico.setDataVencimento(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("AB"));
            historico.setDataAtualizacao(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("W"));
            historico.setDocPgt(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("X"));
            historico.setDocCompensacao(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            historicosList.add(historico);
            contrato.setHistoricos(historicosList);
            mapa.put(contrato.getContrato(), contrato);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            continue;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return mapa;
}
```

**Contrato Class**

```
public class Contrato {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private long contratoId;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contrato", targetEntity = Historico.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Historico> historicos;
```

**Historico Class**

```
public class Historico {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private long historicoId;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="contratoId")
private Contrato contrato;
```

**Save Method**

```
public void salva(Map<String,Contrato> contratoMap) {
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Contrato> entry : contratoMap.entrySet()) {
            Contrato contrato = entry.getValue();
            session.save(contrato);
            System.out.println("contrato salvo");
            List<Historico> historicoList = contrato.getHistoricos();
            for(Historico historico: historicoList){
                session.save(historico);
                System.out.println("historico salvo");
            }
        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tathiana I think you should add a configuration on your annotation on your `private List<Historico> historicos;` attribute to identify it as cascade so you can get rid of the manually inserts on `historico` objects inside your `salva` method. See a good explanation reference here: https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/ Read the CascadeType.PERSIST configuration.

Comment: Hi Jorge! I read the explanation that you indicaded me and I did some changes on my code, and now it's working! thanks

Comment: Glad that I could help! You should add your solution as an answer so it may help others!

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt of all, I was forgetting to set contrato in the historico.

```
try {
            row = worksheet.getRow(i);
            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("L"));
            contratoKey = u.devolveCampoLido(cell);

            if (mapa.containsKey(contratoKey)) {
                contrato = mapa.get(contratoKey);
            } else {
                contrato = new Contrato();
            }
            contrato.setContrato(contratoKey);
            historico = new Historico();
            historico.setContrato(contrato); // I was forgetting this line
```

And I did some modifications on my code as bellow:

```
public class Contrato {
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long contratoId;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "contrato", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Historico> historicos= new ArrayList<Historico>();// instance the list
```

and wrote this method in Contrato class:

```
public void addHistorico(Historico historico) {
    historicos.add(historico);
    historico.setContrato(this);
}
```

and

```
public class Historico {
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long historicoId;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="contratoId")
private Contrato contrato;
```